# Can I use order in JS to find HTML class properties?

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple div classes in an HTML file which are all use the "square" class.  Each div has its own value and order.

```
<div class="square" data-value=1 style="order: 21;">
</div>

<div class="square" data-value=12 style="order: 22;">
</div>
```

The order is randomly assigned within the JS function.  When a user clicks on a particular div class that div is set to firstCard.  The second div class clicked will be set to secondCard.

```
function selectCard() {
if(!hasClicked) {
  hasClicked = true;
  firstCard = this;
  return;
} else {
  hasClicked = false;
  secondCard = this;
}
```

I am able to find the value and order of a selected card with the following syntax:

```
firstCard.dataset.value   
firstCard.style.order
```

However what I want to do is find the value of a card given the order.  So I want to know the value of the card with order 19 even if the card with order 19 is not firstCard or secondCard.

I have tried the `findObjectByKey` method, `findObjectByKey('order',19).value` but this doesn't work.

I also looked into the `grep` method in jQuery but this also isn't working.

Comment: That's possible by going through all elements and their styles, but that would be very inefficient. If you have access to the HTML, add an additional data-attribute `data-order`. That way you can filter inside your JavaScript selector (E.g. `document.querySelector('.square[data-order="19"]')`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works by checking every "square" class to check if the order match.

```
function getValueOfOrder(order){
  var cards = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
  for(i=0;i<cards.length;i++){
    if(cards[i].style.order==order){
      return(cards[i].dataset.value );
    }
  }
}
```

Then just use this command to get The value of the matching tag:

```
getValueOfOrder(orderNumber);
```

*Replace "orderNumber" with the order you want.

Comment: I have been trying a similar function 
`function getValue(card) {
  for(let i=0;i<cards.length;i++) {
    if(cards[i].style.order + 1== secondCard.style.order) {
      return(cards[i].dataset.value);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
`
but this function always returns false.